# Angular JS ng-click not working in ng-repeat like filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I use this code like filter to buttons:

```
<input value="Type1" ng-click="typeF = {type: 'Type1'}" type="button"/>
<input value="Type2" ng-click="typeF = {type: 'Type2'}" type="button"/>
<input value="Type3" ng-click="typeF = {type: 'Type3'}" type="button"/>
<input value="Type4" ng-click="typeF = {type: 'Type4'}" type="button"/>
<input value="All" ng-click="typeF = null" type="button"/>
```

And output data by filtering like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | filter:someN | filter:typeF">
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{product.type}}</td>
    <td>{{product.someNvalue}}</td>
</tr>
```

But I need to use this kind of filter too:

```
<input ng-repeat="product in products | unique:'soneNvalue'" value="{{product.soneNvalue}}" ng-click="$parent.someN = {someNvalue: '{{product.someNvalue}}'}" type="button" >
```

`ng-click` is doing something, but I dod get any output, my list just disapears and all. I use `$parent` scope but it doesnt help much. Can anyone please help :)

Comment: Can you make a live demo? (with JSfiddle for exemple)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/muvagexabuto/1/edit

you don't have to interpolate `{{product.someNvalue}}` inside ng-click

```
<input ng-repeat="product in products |unique:'soneNvalue'"  ng-value="product.someNvalue" 
ng-click="$parent.someN = {someNvalue: product.someNvalue}" 
type="button" >
```

Comment: Thanks. At first it didnt work, but I changet now the `value` to `ng-value`, and before when I removed the interpolate I left these `' '` and removing them it worked like charm. :)